# CRM Dynamics lookup to a view

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have a lookup field on my phone call entity form "call to".

when I try to click the lookup to get to the view "related contact", to choose a contact, I get this error message:

> savedquery With Id = a111290d2-111e-e711-80e3-005056a03ab1 Does Not Exist

Any suggestion?

PS: I have that error with only one record, works fine with all other records.

Comment: You said error with one record only - which record - phone call or contact? Online or on premise?

Answer (score 0):

Create a solution containing phone call entity (preferably all data), export it and unpack. Open customizations.xml and look for this guid - probably it's linked somehow to your lookup. Change this guid to some id of an existing view of contacts. Pack the solution and re-import it back to your organization.

Answer (score 0):

I have troubleshooting steps for you, which will lead to solve the problem.

1.Check in your database if any saved view or user view with this guid (in all environments)

2.Check if Any security role restrictions wrt BU owned/user owned contacts records

3.Also in form lookup field - change the default view & check from properties. See if any related records filter in place or any view restrictions.

[image]